# Quadratic upper bound of a convex function

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, hessian-matrix

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. For some $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$, does the following hold

$$f(x) \le f(a) + \nabla f(a)^\top (x-a) + \frac{1}{2}(x-a)^\top H (x-a)$$

for some matrix $H$?

If we have $\|x^* - a\| \le \epsilon$, where $x^*$ is the minimizer of $f$, can we get some stronger results?

Comment: No, this is not always true. Consider $f(x)=e^x$. Or heck, consider $f(x)=x^4$. If you restrict things to a neighborhood, sure, as long as that neighborhood is small enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I was wondering if we can find $H$ as a function of $\epsilon$, or upper bound the function with some additional assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is known as Lipschitz gradient or smoothness parameter. A convex function $f$ is $\beta$-smooth if it satisfies
$$ f(x) \leq f(a) + \nabla f(a)^\top (x-a) + \frac{1}{2} (x-a)^\top H (x-a) $$
for $H = \beta I$. You can see other properties of smooth function [here](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient).
Your second question is related to strong convex function. Please see [here](https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/strong-convexity) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! The Lipschitz continuous seems what I am looking for. But for the strongly convex, it seems that we can only lower bound the function, not upper bound, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Strong convexity gives you a lower, which can be latter used to bound the norm of optimal solution $\| x - x^\star \|$ based on $f(x) - f(x^\star)$

Comment: Good suggestion! Thanks!